# Pathological listings problem: tilde in \lstinline in a footnote

Tags: listings, footnotes

I seem to be unable to write a tilde in a \lstinline in a footnote.  If you uncomment the only commented line in my minimal working example, you'll see what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
This works:
\begin{lstlisting}
~/path/to/file
\end{lstlisting}

And this works: \lstinline{~/path/to/file}

And this works:\footnote{\lstinline{/path/to/file}}

%But this does \emph{not} work:\footnote{\lstinline{~/path/to/file}}
\end{document}
```

edit: I'm not sure if the answer to this was quite covered in the linked post (listings in footnotes) because that question related to the `listings` environment, not the `lstinline` macro.

Comment: I voted to keep it closed as duplicate as the method suggested by Bruno works like a charm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When `\lstinline` is in the argument to another command it works in a limited way, because it can't perform certain activities. You can try with `\scantokens`, which works, at least with `~`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
This works:
\begin{lstlisting}
~/path/to/file
\end{lstlisting}

And this works: \lstinline{~/path/to/file}

And this works:\footnote{A path: \lstinline{/path/to/file}}

But this does \emph{not} work:\footnote{A path: \scantokens{\lstinline{~/path/to/file}\relax}}
\end{document}
```

[image]