# Problems when defining a general inline code command with listings or verb

Tags: listings, verbatim, code

I am trying to define an inline `\code` command (not language specific, just a smarter `\texttt{}` without the need to escape underscores or tildes, for example). I tried the three versions below based on `listings`.
The best looking would be `\codeThree`, but it suddenly fails when being used in an `enumerate` environment. Can this be fixed?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand*{\codeOne}[1]{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{#1}}
\newcommand*{\codeTwo}[1]{\scantokens{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\codeThree}[1]{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily, literate={~}{{$\sim$}}1 ]{#1}}

\begin{document}
% \codeOne{~/.bashrc} % fails to display the tilde; don't comment in (side-effects on the below)
\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{~/.bashrc} % works
\codeTwo{~/.bashrc} % also works (but only due to the \scantokens command; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175919/pathological-listings-problem-tilde-in-lstinline-in-a-footnote )
\codeThree{~/.bashrc} % works (and shows nicest tilde)
\begin{enumerate}
\item ... but not in an environment (see \codeThree{~/.bashrc}). % fails
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, one could work with `\verb`, but defining a command `\code` which (adjusts the font size and) passes its argument to `\verb` seems pretty hopeless (?) I guess (see https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't define `\code` to take an argument.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand*{\code}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily,literate={~}{{$\sim$}}1]}

\begin{document}

\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{~/.bashrc}        

\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily, literate={~}{{$\sim$}}1]{~/.bashrc}        

\code{~/.bashrc}

\begin{enumerate}
\item ... also in an environment (see \code{~/.bashrc}).        
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You also have the advantage you can call also `\code|...|` as needed in certain cases.

Comment: ... that is awesome, thanks a lot! Given its simplicity, I have to mark this as the preferred answer.

Answer (score 2):

`\lstinline` is also a verbatim command, you can't put it simply in the body of another command (and also outside the enumerate you get messages about open simple groups in the log). Copy the `\lstinline` definition instead:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\codeThree[1][]{%
    \leavevmode\bgroup % \hbox\bgroup --> \bgroup
      \def\lst@boxpos{b}%
      \lsthk@PreSet
     \lstset{flexiblecolumns,basicstyle=\ttfamily,literate={~}{{$\sim$}}1,#1}%
      \lsthk@TextStyle
      \@ifnextchar\bgroup{%
        \afterassignment\lst@InlineG \let\@let@token}%
                         \lstinline@}
 \makeatother                        
\begin{document}
\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{~/.bashrc} % works

\codeThree{~/.bashrc} % works (and shows nicest tilde)
\begin{enumerate}
\item ... and in an environment (see \codeThree{~/.bashrc}). % fails
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ulrike, thanks a lot. With `listings` (first word) you probably mean `\lstinline`. Interesting, seems like a bug in the `listings` package then (*not* to define it the way you did).

Comment: I edited the answer. And it is not a bug, Iistings does define \lstinline this way, I copied the code from the package.

Comment: ah, I now understand the solution better, thanks a ton!