# Macro for lstinline with mathescape results in undefined control sequence

Tags: macros, listings

I have the following issue:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}
% also sets some other options but this bug is indepent of them
\newcommand*{\code}[1]{PREFIX \lstinline[mathescape=true]{#1} SUFFIX}

\begin{document}
\lstinline[mathescape=true]{test 1}

\lstinline[mathescape=true]{$test$ 2}

\code{test 3}

\code{$test$ 4}

\end{document}
```

generates the following and complains about an Undefined control sequence in test 4

test 1

*test* 2

PREFIX test 3 SUFFIX

PREFIX 4 SUFFIX

Obviously I can just use `\lstinline` directly if necessary but I would prefer not too.

I cannot use the answer suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492508/problems-when-defining-a-general-inline-code-command-with-listings-or-verb) as I need to append the prefix and suffix.

Edit:
I have determined that my suffix (`\xpace`) is not necessary and can be handled in a separate way so I will just use the linked answer.

Comment: What are the PREFIX and the SUFFIX?

Comment: PREFIX is a just a string nothing fancy (which was easy to fit into the linked answer).  The suffix is \xspace. Thinking about it the \xspace isn't necessary anymore.   I will use the suggested answer

Comment: And what is `\xspace` supposed to do? There is no reason for using `\xspace` other than for parameterless macros (and it's not even useful in that case).

Comment: \xspace performs fancy look ahead to insert whitespace if necesarry. https://ctan.org/pkg/xspace?lang=en

Comment: No, it has no function whatsoever in the case of `\lstinline`. A space after the closing delimiter will be respected.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate.  It changes how the \code{...}\code{...} is type set (which I generate with other macros but I can make sure spaces are being inserted when necesarry)

Comment: `\code{x}\code{y}` will have no space; `\code{x} \code{y}` will have the space; what would be the function of `\xspace` here?

Comment: \xspace will insert a space if the \code{y} does not begin with punctuation  for instance I have stuff like 
\code{x} -> generates class name 
\code{y} -> .foo.bar 

but in other contexts \code{y} might generate `== var` (I have much larger macro system than is relevant to this question).  But I can insert the \xspace in outer macros to avoid the issue.

Comment: AltF4 no @egreg is correct xspace does nothing useful here (I wrote xspace:-). `\code{x} \code{y}` will always have the space from the source and xspace will do nothing. (I don't recommend xspace even when it does do something but her eit does nothing at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the prefix and the suffix:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\code[1][]{%
  \bgroup
  PREFIX %
  \appto\lst@DeInit{\egroup~SUFFIX}%
  \lstinline[mathescape=true,#1]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\code{$x=1$ abc}

\code|$x=1${abc}|

\code[basicstyle=\ttfamily]|$x=1${abc}|

\end{document}
```

The idea comes from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357339/4427.

However, note that `\xspace` does nothing at all except spinning a few wheels in the case of macros with parameters so you probably don't need the suffix.

[image]